# Tab indent in Linux and Jedit

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

Ive been using Jedit for programming for a few days and I wonder how I can change the tab indent in Jedit. Or can I change the Indent for whole Linux? My second question: I use Python and I would like to have an Indent in the next line after colons. where are the settings for this?

Answer (score 0):

Indentation can be configured by navigating to **Utilities > Global Options > Editing > Tab width**. You said you are coding in python so I strongly recommend that you leave the indentation as it is as python only accepts indentation with standard tabs (4 spaces long).

*Obs: I see no reason why you would use Jedit, you'd better use a decent editor like Atom or Sublime Text.*

Comment: Do you know hot get Indentation after the colons in the next line?

Comment: No. I don't use jedit and this is a very specific question... sry

Comment: Obs: atom and sublime are slow over X. Sometimes you just want something lightweight.